# Creating IBOutlets and IBActions for UIButtons in a static UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I have a `UITableViewController`, designed entirely with `Interface Builder`. The `UITableViewController` is called `DonationTableView`. I am using `Static cells` and the `UITableView` has 6 sections. The reason I am using `Static cells` is because the content can be populated right from within the `Interface Builder` and because each cell contains:

1) A different size

2) A label with it's own text

3) A button

I can also use `AutoLayout` easily within `Interface Builder` to make sure this `DonationTableViewController` looks appropriate on all devices. I know I could use code, but I'm still a newbie here and I'm confident with `Interface Builder`.

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` class called `DonationTableViewCell` and I have assigned that to the `UITableViewCell` in `Interface Builder`. I am now trying to create an `IBAction` and `IBOutlet` for the `UIButton` in each `cell`, but with `Assistant Editor` up, it won't let me actually drag to create that `IBAction` in the way you usually do. If I change the `UITableView` to `Dynamic`, it then allows me to do that, but as mentioned above, I have a fully working `UITableView` with `Static Cells` and I just want to create a `delegate` method in the custom `UITableViewCell` class so that I can click the button and run an action.

[image]

So essentially, I want to be able to assign an `IBAction` to the `UIButton` in the `UITableViewCell`. How would I go about doing that?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Is DonationTableView class inherited from UITableViewController? You can check it from DonationTableView.h.

Comment: Thanks @alicanbatur - the DonationTableView inherits from the UITableViewController and the DonationTableViewCell inherits from the UITableViewCell. The first answer has fixed this though - thanks for reaching out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag the button outlet or IBAction to your `TableviewController`

[image]

Comment: Dear @Leo - many thanks for the answer here. If I do that, it works, but then can I basically call an action from that IBAction of the UIButton to for example, present a view controller?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help Leo - that worked like a charm and I can't believe how simple it was and how complicated I was trying to make it!

Answer (score 1):

For use `UiButton`in `Tableview` you need to follow this 2 Steps.

(1) Give UIButton Tag Inside Tableview.

Ex : Here your Button is identify with uniq tag .And also Give UIButton Method

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 cell.button.tag = indexPath.row;
 [cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(btn_Clicked_Method:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

(2) In UIButton Method

```
- (IBAction)btn_Clicked_Method:(id)sender {
    NSInteger tag= ((UIButton *)sender).tag
    NSLog(@"Button row %ld",(long)tag);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Maulik for reaching out - that's really helpful. The other answer was just a bit easier to implement, but thanks very much!